# Auto screen brightness in X1 Carbon 8th gen in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, lenovo, brightness, thinkpad, sensors

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04 on a X1 Carbon 8th gen and I am surprised to find that there is no configuration related to auto screen brightness in system settings. Do I need to install additional drivers/softwares to get it enabled in Ubuntu 22.04?

Note: Installing Windows in dual boot is not an option.

Comment: it seems the option should be under "power saving options" if it does exist, did you check there?

Comment: apparently you can also do it via terminal with `gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power ambient-enabled true`, however this instruction is a bit old and I'm not sure that it works on 22.04, which is why it's a comment.

Comment: @Esther it is not available in the `power saving options` under `power` category in settings?